# Java XML Numeric Character References

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am having an issue when I parse an XML document that has numeric character references (ie &#xA0).  The problem I am running into is that when the document is parsed, the & is replaced with &amp ; (without the space before the ;), so my parsed document will contain &amp ;#xA0;.  How do I stop this from happening?  I have tried using `xmlDoc.setExpandEntityReferences(false)`, but that doesnt seem to change anything.

Here is my code for parsing the document:

```
public static Document getXmlDoc(File xmlFile) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXExeption, IOException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
    factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    return builder.parse(xmlFile);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The XML that is parsed form the above code is modified and then written back to a file.  The code to do this is below:

```
public static File saveXmlDoc(Document xmlDocument, String outputToDir, String outputFilename) throws IOException {
    String outputDir = outputToDir;
    if (!outputDir.endWith(File.separator)) outputDir += File.separator;
    if (!new FIle(outputDir).exists()) new File(outputDir).mkdir();
    File xmlFile = new File(outputDir + outputFilename);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
    StreamResult saveResult = new StreamResult(outputDir + outputFilename);
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDocument);
    transformer.transform(source, saveResult);

    return xmlFile;
}
```

EDIT 2:

Fixed a typo for `factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);`.

EDIT 3 - My Solution:

Since my reputation is too low to answer my own question, here is the solution I used to fix all of this.

Here are the functions I changed in order to resolve this issue:

To get the XML Document:

```
    public static Document getXmlDoc(File xmlFile) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        return builder.parse(xmlFile);
    }
```

To save the XML Document:

```
    public static File saveXmlDoc(Document xmlDocument, String outputToDir, String outputFilename) throws Exception {
        readNodesForHexConversion(xmlDocument.getChildNodes());
        String xml = getXmlAsString(xmlDocument);

        // write the xml out to a file
        Exception writeError = null;
        File xmlFile = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            if (!new File(outputToDir).exists()) new File(outputToDir).mkdir();
            xmlFile = new File(outputToDir + outputFilename);
            if (!xmlFile.exists()) xmlFile.createNewFile();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(xmlFile);

            byte[] xmlBytes = xml.getBytes("UTF-8");
            fos.write(xmlBytes);
            fos.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            writeError = ex;
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) fos.close();
            if (writeError != null) throw writeError;
        }

        return xmlFile;
    }
```

To convert the XML Document to String:

```
        public static String getXmlAsString(Document xmlDocument) throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(xmlDocument);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
    Transformer transformer;
    transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(domSource, result);
    return writer.toString();
}
```

Comment: The resulting XML should be treated as equivalent by anything parsing it *as* XML... why is it a problem for you?

Comment: It is a problem because the original XML is written that way (without the &amp ;) and when I write it back out, it needs to be written out the same.  For myself, this shouldnt be an issue, but I have no idea how other systems are parsing this XML, so I am trying not to change things like this.

Comment: So you don't *actually* know that it's going to cause any problems? Do you know which other systems *will* be parsing it, and can you ask their QA departments to check whether they can handle the should-be-equivalent XML?

Comment: No, I don't actually know.  Yes, I could ask if it can handle it.  The question _still_ remains, though.  Can it be stopped?  I _will_ ask if it can be handled with the &amp ;, but in the meantime, I want to fix it to look like the original numerical character reference.  If they can handle the &amp ;, I will change it back, but getting an answer could take more time than I have, and I certainly do not want to produce 100's of invalid XML docs only to find out after-the-fact that their parsers _cannot_ handle it.

Comment: Have reread the question, and it looks like something more is going on, and it *wouldn't* be equivalent. Trying to reproduce now.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem at the moment. Here's a short but complete program which tries to:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] xml = "<foo>&#xA0;</foo>".getBytes("UTF-8");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml));
        Element element = document.getDocumentElement();
        String text = element.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        System.out.println(text.length()); // Prints 1
        System.out.println((int) text.charAt(0)); // Prints 160
    }
}
```

Now it's not clear from the above XML would be written out again - and it would help if you'd show the code you're using to do that - but it's clear that the single-character value of the text node is *not* being read as an ampersand followed by "#xA0;" separately, as I *believe* your question describes it, so I'd be really surprised to see it written out as "&#xA0;".

Can you write a similar short but complete program which *does* demonstrate the problem? Will continue to try to do so myself.

Comment: BTW...as I edited just now in my OP, the `factory.setIgnoreElementContentWhitespace(true)` was a typo and should have been `setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace`.  I hand typed this because I am posting this on my PC, but the code is on my Mac, so you are seeing the real code.

Comment: I copied your code above and, oddly enough, it produced the desired NBSP character (not á...&#xA0 is a NBSP).  So why is it that when it parses the XML file like my code above, it prints &amp ;#xA0;?

Comment: @Ashaelon: I've edited my code to not try to display the NBSP itself, but to print the Unicode value, which is of course fine. I strongly suspect that your XML file *really does* have `&amp;#xA0` in it - how have you been looking at it? Open it in notepad.

Comment: I verified that it was written as `&#xA0;` and not `&amp ;#xA0;`. I look at it in TextMate (and TextEdit) on my Mac.

Comment: Is there some place I can post my XML file for you to look at?  Maybe that would help?

Comment: Sure - dropbox or somewhere similar. Post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, too.

Comment: I took a step back and noticed that I had some other issue.  For some reason, when I was converting the XML Doc to string, it was being read with UTF-16 encoding, even though I wrote the file in UTF-8 encoding.  Oddly enough, when I switched from using the LSSerializer to using Transformer to StringWriter, the problem seemed to have gone away, but now I have an issue with saving the document to file.  It is saving it with the `&amp ;#xA0;`, but I fixed that by converting the XML Doc to string and using a FileOutputStream to write the file.  Thanks for all your help, Jon.

Comment: See Edit 3 in my OP for the solution I used.

Comment: @Ashaelon: Why were you reading it into a string to start with? Read it directly as a string. But anyway, I'm glad it's sorted :)

Comment: I was reading it as a string just to see what was loading into the Document Object, and printing it out to the console, for troubleshooting.  I am thinking that I was being misled as to what the issue was because the conversion to string was giving me the wrong information.  It lead me to believe that the parsing of the file was incorrect, when, in fact, it was writing back to the file that was actually incorrect (if that makes any sense).